# avatars that stay on top of backgrounds never work?

Tags: html, css, avatar

This is a dumb question for some, probably, but I don't know much of HTML so please bear with me.
I'm trying to setup an HTML my friend did for me for a site, an user HTML. But, for some reason, the original code she gave me for my avatar doesnt work. Everything else does, even other images, except the avatar.
[This is how it's supposed to look like (this was her screenshot of the preview)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIW2j.png), but instead, [looked like this on my end.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFlY9.png)

```
<!---------------- TOP BANNER -------- CHOOSE A SEAMLESS PATTERN ----------------------------------------------> <div class="card border-0 modal-open bg-faded" style="border-radius: 1em;  box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px rgba(0,0,0,.2);">
  <div style="background: url('https://eskipaper.com/images/cute-flower-pattern-wallpaper-1.jpg') fixed; height: 200px;" 
  class="card-block" ></div>
  
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-3 pr-lg-0">
        <div class="card card-block d-block bg-faded border-0 rounded-0">
          
          <!---------------- 200 x 200 AVATAR IMAGE ---------------------------------------------->
           <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/840360608041402441/861941534588010496/unknown.png" 
           class="bg-faded p-2 rounded-circle d-block mx-auto mb-2" style="max-height: 200px; margin-top: -100px;">
```

This was the code she sent me (the focus is the avatar part, but decided to upload the entire thing).
After a bit of mumble jumbo, she tried to fix it to something else (the avatar section) to see if the image would show up. [And so it did, but not in the original way intended.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMvbG.png) So she assumed my PC basically hates me.

```
                <!-- 【 Avatar 】 
    ------------------------------------------------ -->
    <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/840360608041402441/861941534588010496/unknown.png" class="rounded-circle mx-auto p-2 bg-faded" style="width:200px;margin-top:-75px;">
```

This was the 2nd code she sent, and worked.

This issue has happened to me before with another entirely different HTML for the same purpose. If I disable WYSIWYG the original code *does work*, [just not how it's supposed to.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0atb8.png) It ends up separated from the background.

So this boggles my mind. Is it my PC or just really, horrible luck with HTML?

For now I'm sitting with the WYSIWYG disabled, to have at least a readable avatar. Any help on this, if it's something fixable?
Sorry for any bad term, confusion, or something of the like. I'm illiterate when it comes to coding.

EDIT1: I tried to see it in a [code preview made for the specific site I'm using](https://th.circlejourney.net), and it does show up like intended (see image 1), but when copy pasting that code for the live site it breaks (img 2). This is making this all more confusing.

Comment: probably a background-color in the way ? and boostrap library not linked or the wrong version ?  `<div class="card card-block d-block bg-faded bg-transparent border-0 rounded-0"` would help ?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I added that in between and it didn't end up as intended, but had the same result as the last img (when I disabled WYSIWYG). At least I can use/edit it in a normal code view now...

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the problem with something like this is that you not only have to worry about the HTML being sent to you but also the styles that are already on your site influencing it after you put it in.

As an example, here's a simplified version that should mostly match the intended look/feel. It only uses inline styles. View it standalone on this site and I bet it's mostly what you want. If you paste it into yours, it MAY work. The point is the MAY. It's not "your PC hates you" but instead that html/css layout can get pretty complex and it's going to take some studying on your part to figure out what's getting applied and how to properly integrate any snippet with your site.

```html
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center;background: #222;">
  <div style="background: url('https://eskipaper.com/images/cute-flower-pattern-wallpaper-1.jpg') fixed; height: 200px; width: 100%;"></div>
  <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/840360608041402441/861941534588010496/unknown.png" style="max-height: 200px; margin-top: -100px;border-radius: 200px; border: 10px solid #222;">
</div>
```

Comment: When I added it it just broke the entire thing! Like, I can see in the preview how it's meant to be, but it breaks everything else in the code.
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/840360608041402441/862762434749792292/unknown.png like, this broke

Comment: Put the rest of it inside the `</div>`